# Pandas - Count total quantity of item and remove unique values that have a total quantity less than 5

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a simplified table that resembles my df below. A clothing item such as, blue_shirt, could appear more than once in the column with a different value under Quantity_ordered each time it appears (1st time it appears there is only 1 unit under Quantity_ordered, 2nd time there are 3 units).

```
    Item_ID       Item            Price     Quantity_ordered     Category           Status 
1    2110       blue_shirt       20.00           1             Men's Fashion      Refund
2    2111       red_shirt        20.00           1             Women's Fashion     Refund
45   2165       green_pants      30.00           2             Women's Fashion     Refund
68   2176       tan_khakis       30.00           1             Men's Fashion       Refund
...   ...          ...             ...           ...               ...               ...
126  2250       white_sneakers   60.00           1             Men's Fashion       Refund
```

I want to condense each repeated item into one and find what the total value under Quantity_ordered is for each item. There are many single item returns which are not necessary to display so I also want to remove any items that have a total quantity less than 5.

I tried to count the number of times an item repeated itself using this line

```
df.groupby('Item').Quantity_ordered.nunique()
```

And the output was

```
    Item          
  blue_shirt       1
  yellow_shirt     1
  brown_shirt      1
  tan_pants        1
            ...
  white_sneakers   1
  blue_sandals     1
  Name: Quantity_ordered, Length: 2487  dtype: int64
```

I'm lost on how to manipulate the data and would assume two functions must be combined to achieve what I'm looking for. For context, my goal is to add a new column that shows how many units of each item appear in the df and order it greatest to least to show which item has the most returns.

*This is one of my first projects so if my format is incomplete, if I'm missing info or need a different approach feel free to let me know. Any constructive feedback is very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `df.groupby(['Item']).Quantity_ordered.nunique()[lambda x: x < 5]`

Comment: dont you need a `sum` and not a `nunique` ?

Comment: Agreed. I think OP is trying to do a sum. instead of `nunique`, it has to be `sum`

Answer (score 2):

You simply get the size of each group by doing the following:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Item').agg(np.size)
```

You can refer to this example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                              'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
   Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1  Falcon      370.0
2  Parrot       24.0
3  Parrot       26.0
```

If I wanted to count how many occurrences of each happened I can just do this:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Animal').agg(np.size)
print grouped
```

Output:

```
        Max Speed
Animal           
Falcon        2.0
Parrot        2.0
```

You can refer to [aggregate functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) as well as [group_by](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_groupby.htm) for better understanding

Answer (score 2):

use `transform` to apply a groupby operation without modifying your index along with a boolean condition.

```
print(df)

 Item_ID            Item  Price  Quantity_ordered         Category  Status
0     2110      blue_shirt   20.0                10    Men's Fashion  Refund
1     2111       red_shirt   20.0                 1  Women's Fashion  Refund
2     2165     green_pants   30.0                25  Women's Fashion  Refund
3     2176      tan_khakis   30.0                 1    Men's Fashion  Refund
4     2250  white_sneakers   60.0                 1    Men's Fashion  Refund
```

---

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Item')['Quantity_ordered'].transform('sum') >= 5]

   Item_ID         Item  Price  Quantity_ordered         Category  Status
0     2110   blue_shirt   20.0                10    Men's Fashion  Refund
2     2165  green_pants   30.0                25  Women's Fashion  Refund
```